# Outbound integration (wrriten in Apex) not sending all requests

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, integration

need help with the following problem:
I have a Salesforce Flow, which is **triggered** whenever an Order record is **activated**, this creates a platform event.

I have an OrderService I've written as an Apex Action to invoke from the Platform Event flow.
It:

- Retrieves the information from the Order record & related records
- Converts the data to a map
- It then uses a method to send the information to another class which is responsible for posting a HTTP request
- In this second class, a method sends these HTTP requests to the inbound endpoint & retrieve a response which is then logged

The problem I am facing, is that I can only ever send one request. If I try to activate 2+ Orders, only 1 request is ever sent.

Solution I've tried:

- My thought process was that it was due to govern limits, so I have built the queueable interface around this code, so that the Apex processes run async. It doesn't seem to have solved the problem.
- Scheduled Flow - This doesn't work for obvious reasons as activating all Orders at once doesn't help

Thanks for any input.

edit:
[image: Trigger to start platform event]

[image: Dispatch Order to Service Bus, inputs are "{!$RecordId} from Platform Event.]

OrderService Class:

```
public class OrderService {

public class InvalidRequestException extends Exception {}

public static Boolean SendMessage(Id recordId) {

    // Set Action
    String action = AzureServiceBus.ACTION_ORDER;

    // Get Record as Map from Datastore
    Map<String, Object> dataMap = OrderService.GetRecordAsMap(recordId);
    if (dataMap == null) throw new InvalidRequestException('Invalid Order Id');

    
    Map<String, Object> struct = new Map<String, Object> {
        'data' => OrderService.GetRecordAsMap(recordId),
        'action' => action
    };

    /// Serialise to JSON
    String payload = JSON.serialize(struct);
    System.Debug(payload);

    // Send to Azure Service Bus.
    return AzureServiceBus.SendMessage(action, payload);
}

private static Order getRecord(Id recordId) {
    if (recordId == null) return null;

    List<Order> lst = [
        SELECT
            Id, AccountId, ActivatedById, ActivatedDate, Area_or_Subsidiary__c, Plan_ID__c, BillingAddress, BillToContactId, CompanyAuthorizedById,Billing_Email__c,
            CompanyAuthorizedDate, ContractId, CreatedById, Customer_Type_EA_or_CSP__c, Customer_Contact__c, CustomerAuthorizedById, CustomerAuthorizedDate, 
            Description, EffectiveDate, EndDate, Fulfilment_Status__c, IsReductionOrder, LastModifiedById, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingPostalCode, BillingState, BillingCountry,
            OpportunityId, OrderNumber, OrderReferenceNumber, OriginalOrderId, OwnerId, PoDate, PoNumber, Pricebook2Id, QuoteId, RecordTypeId,
            ShippingAddress, ShipToContactId, Status, TotalAmount, PartnerAccountId__c, Billing_Mode__c, Partner_Success_Manager_ID__c, PartnerUserEmail__c, tech_pre_sales_id__c, Type,
            (
                SELECT 
                     Id, AvailableQuantity, CreatedById, Customer_Deployment_Geo__c, Description, EndDate, LastModifiedById, ListPrice, OrderId, 
                    OrderItemNumber, OriginalOrderItemId, requested_VMs__c, Product_Family__c, Product2Id, Quantity, Asset__c, QuoteLineItemId, Location__c, Order_Type__c, Requested_VM_Count__c,requestedProvisionDate__c, ServiceDate, Deployment_Type__c, DeploymentType__c, Subscription_ID__c, TotalPrice, 
                    UnitPrice
                FROM
                    OrderItems
            )
        FROM
            Order
        WHERE
            Id = :recordId
    ];

    return (lst.size() != 1) ? null : lst[0];
}

public static Map<String, Object> GetRecordAsMap(Id recordId) {
    // Get Record from Datastore
    Order record = OrderService.getRecord(recordId);
    if (record == null) return null;

    return OrderService.GetRecordAsMap(record);
}

public static Map<String, Object> GetRecordAsMap(Order record) {
    if (record == null) return null;

    return new Map<String, Object> {
        'products' => OrderService.GetProductRecordsAsMap(record.OrderItems),
        'totalAmount' => record.TotalAmount,
        'DrMPlanID' => record.Plan_ID__c,
        'owner' => UserService.GetRecordAsMap(record.OwnerId),
        'account' => AccountService.GetRecordAsMap(record.AccountId),
        'billingAddress' => record.BillingStreet + ' ' + record.BillingCity + ' ' + record.BillingPostalCode + ' ' + record.BillingState + ' ' + record.BillingCountry,
        'partner' => AccountService.GetRecordAsMap(record.PartnerAccountId__c),
        'partnerUserEmail' => record.PartnerUserEmail__c,
        'billingMode' => record.Billing_Mode__c,
        'billingEmail' => record.Billing_Email__c,
        'customer' => ContactService.GetRecordAsMap(record.Customer_Contact__c, true),
        'customerType' => record.Customer_Type_EA_or_CSP__c,
        'partnerSuccessManager' => UserService.GetRecordAsMap(record.Partner_Success_Manager_ID__c),
        'technicalPreSales' => UserService.GetRecordAsMap(record.tech_pre_sales_id__c),
        'activatedBy' => UserService.GetRecordAsMap(record.ActivatedById),
        'activatedDate' => record.ActivatedDate,
        'endDate' => record.EndDate,
        'startDate' => record.EffectiveDate,
        'fulfilmentStatus' => record.Fulfilment_Status__c,
        'type' => record.Type,
        'status' => record.Status,
        'orderReferenceNumber' => record.OrderReferenceNumber,
        'purchaseOrderNumber' => record.PoNumber,
        'orderNumber' => record.OrderNumber,
        'salesforceKey' => record.Id
    };
}

public static List<Object> GetProductRecordsAsMap(List<OrderItem> recordList) {
    List<Object> responseList = new List<Object>();

    if (recordList != null) {
        for (OrderItem record : recordList) {
            responseList.add(new Map<String, Object>{
                'totalPrice' => record.TotalPrice,
                'unitPrice' => record.UnitPrice,
                'listPrice' => record.ListPrice,
                'location' => record.Location__c,
                'requested_vm_count' => record.Requested_VMs__c,
                'asset' => AssetService.GetRecordAsMap(record.Asset__c),
                'requestedProvisionDate' => record.requestedProvisionDate__c,
                'customerDeploymentGeography' => record.Customer_Deployment_Geo__c,
                'orderType' => record.Order_Type__c,
                'subscriptionId' => record.Subscription_ID__c,
                'productFamily' => record.Product_Family__c,
                'deploymentType' => record.DeploymentType__c,
                'product' => ProductService.GetRecordAsMap(record.Product2Id),
                'quantity' => record.Quantity,
                'endDate' => record.EndDate,
                'startDate' => record.ServiceDate,
                'description' => record.Description,
                'salesforceKey' => record.Id
            });
        }
    }

    return responseList;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Package As Flow Component.

public class OrderServiceRequest {

    @InvocableVariable(label='Record ID' required=true)
    public String RecordId;
}

public class OrderServiceResponse {

    @InvocableVariable(label='Success')
    public Boolean Success;
}

@InvocableMethod(label='Dispatch Order to Service Bus' description='Send the specified order to an Azure Service Bus' category='Order')
public static List<OrderServiceResponse> SendMessageFromFlow(List<OrderServiceRequest> requestList) {
    List<OrderServiceResponse> responseList = new List<OrderServiceResponse>();

    for (OrderServiceRequest request : requestList) {
        OrderServiceResponse response = new OrderServiceResponse();
        response.Success = OrderService.SendMessage(request.RecordId);
        responseList.add(response);
    }

    return responseList;
}
```

}

From there, SendMessage invokes the AzureServiceBus class to form a HTTP request.

Comment: I suggest sharing screenshot of your flow and your innovacable apex.

Comment: Are you processing all received events? Do you find the records using data from the platform event itself?

Comment: I think you need to add your InvocableMethod code; if you have copied the examples, these fail to process all received inputs (typically processing just `input[0]`).

Comment: Apologies have shared screenshots. 

@PhilW - Yes all received events are being processed.
I have added the code that is invoked (OrderService) above.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that this was due to Salesforce platform events batching requests into the Salesforce Flow that invoked the Apex Class.

Using queues at the first class to handle each request before the next one helped solve this issue.

Also, please don't downvote a question with details makes no sense.